# VSCode: Attempted to update project that is not loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense, csproj, omnisharp

I am using VSC for Unity v2019.4. I have the package from package manager installed. Also I have installed dotnet. The thing is that when I open VSC (through Unity) it shows in the output:
**Attempted to update project that is not loaded: C:\workspaces\Unity\MyGame\Assembly-CSharp.csproj**.
am able to use the editor, but the Intellisense is not working. I also have tried to change the omnisharp version to latest and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things in order to make `Visual Studio Code` works properly with `Unity`.
First of all make sure that the editor package is installed in your project via `Package Manager`. Latest version should be installed.
Just to be sure it's better to close the project, delete `Library` folder and all `.csproj` and `.sln` files.
Then you can open your project in `Unity` again, wait it to load and try to remember to open scripts not by double clicking, but instead use right click in `Project` window and select `Open C# Project`. This will load the scripts without any issues.

Comment: I have done this. I deleted all .csproj and .sln files and library folder. I make sure of having  latest visual studio code package. But when I entered Unity I got this message: **Rebuilding Library because the asset database could not be found!** then I opened C# project as told, but I still got this fails : [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: C:\workspaces\Unity\MyGame\Assembly-CSharp.csproj this one and other 2:  The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still having this problem, try to install [.net framework 4.7.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net471)

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling then reinstalling vs code and dotnet latest version. Also make sure vs code is installed in a folder with permissions to edit. If not it will not save any files until you run as admin